# How to change click behaviour in textarea so that it shows cursor position and doesn't select a character?

Tags: textarea, textselection, cursor-position

I have a textarea and when I run on one machine, clicking does this:

[image]

and on the other it does this:

[image]

Comment: Note ... I've realised that the choice of browser is also an issue. On firefox I get the second result, but Chrome gives the first result ... both on the same webpage from the same server.

Comment: The mystery deepens. The second image is what I'd call normal, while the first is strange and makes editing difficult.  When I woke up this morning and started my browser (Chrome) which had been displaying the strange behaviour ... it was gone and the normal behaviour was back again.